# Not enough height for my EditText in AlertDialog

Tags: android

I am new to Android Java (and java). I am trying to modify a package I am using in my react-native app.

Currently when in landscape mode my `EditText` is getting cutoff like in screenshot below.

I was trying to modify this library, so I modified the `alertDialog.setView` call here - https://github.com/shimohq/react-native-prompt-android/blob/master/android/src/main/java/im/shimo/react/prompt/RNPromptFragment.java#L149

```
 alertDialog.setView(input, 50, 15, 50, 0);
```

Apparently this is "extra space". I changed it to:

```
 alertDialog.setView(input, 50, 0, 50, 0);
```

So the top extra space is 0, but this didn't make it big enough, it just moved the dialog up.

May you please share with me what I would change in the `alertDialog` to make sure the height fits the contents of the dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apparently this is "extra space". I changed it to:
>
> alertDialog.setView(input, 50, 0, 50, 0);

According [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), next 4 params after your view are used for extra spacing, used as a padding.

So you should use something like

```
alertDialog.setView(input, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

or just

```
alertDialog.setView(input);
```

Also your input should have `MATCH_PARENT` width and `WRAP_CONTENT` height, not a fixed size.

Comment: Thanks Florescu I will try this out. They have it as `MATCH_PARENT` for both - https://github.com/shimohq/react-native-prompt-android/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/edit_text.xml#L4 - so I would change it to `WRAP_PARENT` here?

Comment: WRAP_CONTENT not WRAP_PARENT for height

Comment: Thank you @seekingStillness!

Comment: @seekingStillness My bad. Fixed now.

Comment: @Noitidart `WRAP_CONTENT` will use how much is need to be displayed, on the other side, `MATCH_PARENT` will use all the available space from the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of an EditText I have in my app

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_edit_name"
    android:hint="Edit Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_edit_dark"
    tools:ignore="TextFields"
    />

    final EditText et_name = view.findViewById(R.id.et_edit_name);
    et_name.setText("PrePopulated Text");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(JarDetailActivity.this);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            dialog.dismiss();
            String entered =et_name.getText().toString();

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

I tried to clean it up a bit, so I might have a bracket or two wrong

Comment: Thanks this is interesting!

Comment: This was very helpful because I had no idea to use lower case "wrap_content". Thank you very much for sharing. I was trying to force uppercase "WRAP_CONTENT". So just doing this fixes it up huh? Is there a way to tell android to center the dialog in the screen?

Comment: Yes, you will want to set this in your xml view.  Either use `android:layout_gravity="center"` or `android:gravity="center"` or sometimes both.

Comment: Thank you @seeking! However the dialog I create without a xml view, is it still possible to do this? This is how the dialog gets created - https://github.com/shimohq/react-native-prompt-android/blob/master/android/src/main/java/im/shimo/react/prompt/RNPromptFragment.java#L157 - it seems it has no related xml.

Comment: I'm not well versed in fragments.  sorry.